# Twitterizer fails when using geotags or uploading media

Tags: c#, .net, twitterizer

So I noticed two bugs in Twitterizer:
1. When specifying Latitude, Longitude, and a Place ID in the StatusUpdateOptions, the Longitude is dropped and retains its default value, 0, essentially breaking the geotag feature.
2. When using geotags while uploading an image via UpdateWithMedia(), sending the tweet fails with "Invalid coordinates" as error message.
I stumbled across [this bug report on Twitterizer's own bug tracker](http://pm.twitterizer.net/issues/103), but appearently it was ignored and as such didn't get fixed. I tried recompiling Twitterizer with the changes the bug reporter suggested, but that didn't do anything, my tweets still fail.
Can anyone help me work around or fix those bugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out MetroTwit Loop was the culprit, not Twitterizer, which, by the way, worked perfectly.
I've sent the developers of MetroTwit a bug report. Basically, problem solved.